# c - *(void **) &(int[2]){0,PAGE_SIZE}; meaning?

Tags: c, pointers

## Context

Reading some kernel code.

## Problem

I cannot get my head on what this line is meaning

```
*(void **) &(int[2]){0,PAGE_SIZE};
```

and more, what does this means

```
{0,PAGE_SIZE}
```

To me it doesn't look like a function with that comma.

What could be going on with this code ? I don't understand the indirections here.

Is it a function or a cast ? What does the bracket part means ? Seems so convoluted to me but definitely has a meaning.

Comment: [Compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Compound-Literals.html).

Comment: :sigh: This is what happens when people try to get cute. Should probably just be `int[] const foo = {0, PAGE_SIZE}; *(void**)(&foo);`

Comment: @BillyONeal: Inside a macro, this would make sense (however GCC special block syntax would help here, since this is kernel code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(int[2]) { 0, PAGE_SIZE }
```

is an expression (called *compound literal*) whose value is an array of two `int`s. The address of this array is taken, casted to `void **`, and dereferenced.

The net result is a reinterpretation of the array contents as a pointer to void.

Note that you *can* take the address of a compound literal, as they are lvalues. See eg. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739998/array-as-compound-literal).

Comment: How can you take the address of an expression? I thought you could only do that to lvalues.

Comment: Because when you talk about arrays,the address only is referenced by default!Your doubt would have been valid for primitives like int type variables,etc. @templatetypedef...

Comment: @shekharsuman I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. If you give the *name* of an array as an lvalue, then it implicitly decays to a pointer to the first element of the array. Here, though, since the array results from a cast, it doesn't seem like the same rules should apply. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @templatetypedef-*Exactly* for the first statement! Whereas,array is resulting from cast as well it is trivially array because of `{...}`! You just try to assign `{...}` to a non-pointer OR non-array variable,and you'll receive the error!

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm guessing that the compound literal syntax is what coerces it into a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @remyabel Even if that's the case, you can't apply the `&` operator to non-lvalues (or can you?)

Comment: @templatetypedef-Why do you think that `&` can't be applied to non-lvalues? What about references? Haven't I understood your point properly! Also,the first point to add is that `compound literal` has a much bigger role to play!

Comment: @templatetypedef-Why don't you verify it by checking the very first example on this link--->`https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Compound-Literals.html`

Comment: @templatetypedef: IIRC, compound literals *are* lvalues (ie. they are not casts but special constructs).

Comment: Got it - I didn't realize that compound literals are defined to be lvalues. Everything makes sense now!

Comment: @templatetypedef: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739998/array-as-compound-literal

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. My way to master c is still long I think :)